# bulk insert in db table

Tags: python, database

I'm having an array I want to insert in a single query in a table. Any idea?

Comment: which RDBMS are you talking about?

Comment: And which ORM, if any?  You haven't given us nearly enough information.

Comment: This is a first-class feature of the DBAPI. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/  Since .executemany does this, it can't be your question.  What are you asking?

Comment: @S.Lott: why can't it be OP's question? majority of all python's problems are solved by stdlib functions.

Comment: @SilentGhost: While true that most things are in the standard library, I sill have to ask what's *really* going on.  In some cases, there is profound confusion.  In other cases, they simply didn't read.  I -- personally -- need to know the difference so I can answer the *real* question, not the stated question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using dbapi to access the database, then the connection.executemany() method works.

```
con.executemany("INSERT INTO some_table (field) VALUES (?)", [(v,) for v in your_array])
```

The format of the bindparameter depends on the database, sqlite uses ?, mysql uses %s, postgresl uses %s or %(key)s if passing in dicts. To abstract this you can use SQLAlchemy:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
metadata = sa.MetaData(sa.create_engine(database_url))
some_table = Table('some_table', metadata, autoload=True)
some_table.insert([{'field': v} for v in your_array]).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

As uneffective (individual inserts) one-liner:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'x': 2, 'y': 4}, {'somethig': 'other', 'otherfield': 5, 'y': 6}]
table = 'table_name'
connection = connect() # DBAPI connection

map(connection.cursor().execute, ('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)' % ('table', ','.join(x), ','.join(['%s'] * len(x))) for x in data), (x.values() for x in data))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use the [COPY statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-copy.html).